# Reminder Command Issue in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot reminder command, however, I am running through an issue.

When I do the command, it executes the sleep time perfectly, however, it doesn't show the reminder that I have set.

Example: When I do `/reminder 5m Fix the server`, it should send `Alright, I will remind you about Fix the server in 5 minutes.`, However, it is sending this instead: `Alright, I will remind you about {} in 5 minutes.`
And also when I don't include the reminder argument it should send an error message, but it does nothing instead.

Here is my code:

```
@bot.command(case_insensitive = True, aliases = ["remind", "remindme", "remind_me"])
@commands.bot_has_permissions(attach_files = True, embed_links = True)
async def reminder(ctx, *time, **reminder):
    user = ctx.message.author 
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Please specify a proper duration, send `reminder_help` for more information.", description="", color=0x55a7f7, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_footer(text="If you have any questions, suggestions or bug reports, please join our support Discord Server: link hidden", icon_url=f"{bot.user.avatar_url}")
    embed2 = discord.Embed(title="Please specify what do you want me to remind you about.", description="", color=0x55a7f7, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    embed2.set_footer(text="If you have any questions, suggestions or bug reports, please join our support Discord Server: link hidden", icon_url=f"{bot.user.avatar_url}")    
    embed3 = discord.Embed(title="You have specified a too long duration!\nMaximum duration is 90 days.", color=0x55a7f7, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    embed3.set_footer(text="If you have any questions, suggestions or bug reports, please join our support Discord Server: link hidden", icon_url=f"{bot.user.avatar_url}")        
    embed4 = discord.Embed(title="You have specified a too short duration!\nMinimum duration is 5 minutes.", color=0x55a7f7, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    embed4.set_footer(text="If you have any questions, suggestions or bug reports, please join our support Discord Server: link hidden", icon_url=f"{bot.user.avatar_url}")      
    seconds = 0
    if reminder is None:
        await ctx.send(embed=embed2) # Error message
        return
    for i in time:
        if i.lower().endswith("d"):
            seconds += int(i[:-1]) * 60 * 60 * 24
            counter = f"{seconds//60//60//24} days"
        if i.lower().endswith("h"):
            seconds += int(i[:-1]) * 60 * 60  
            counter = f"{seconds//60//60} hours"
        elif i.lower().endswith("m"):
            seconds += int(i[:-1]) * 60
            counter = f"{seconds//60} minutes"
        elif i.lower().endswith("s"):
            seconds += int(i[:-1])  
            counter = f"{seconds} seconds"
        if seconds == 0:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed) # Error message
            return
        elif seconds < 300:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed4) # Error message
            return
        elif seconds > 7776000:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed3) # Error message
            return
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"Alright, I will remind you about {reminder} in {counter}.")
            await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
            await ctx.send(f"Hi, you asked me to remind you about {reminder} {counter} ago.")
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no problem in the code. You said that just `{reminder}` part is not working, right?

Comment: Yeah, the reminder part isn't working, it should display what the reminder is but instead it shows empty brackets like this {}.
And also it doesn't send an error when I put no reminder at all.

Comment: Would you try to change `async def reminder(ctx, *time, **reminder):` with `async def reminder(ctx, time, *, reminder):`?

Comment: I tried replacing it with what you said above, but for some reason that makes the seconds counter always 0 regardless of what I put, I am not sure what is causing that exactly, though I am assuming I also have to edit some parts of the code to fit the arguments changes.

Comment: where are the embed1,2,3,4?

Comment: I have edited the question and included them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved your question with changing a few thing"s" in your code. So here is the new code:

```
@client.command(case_insensitive = True, aliases = ["remind", "remindme", "remind_me"])
@commands.bot_has_permissions(attach_files = True, embed_links = True)
async def reminder(ctx, time, *, reminder):
    print(time)
    print(reminder)
    user = ctx.message.author
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0x55a7f7, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_footer(text="If you have any questions, suggestions or bug reports, please join our support Discord Server: link hidden", icon_url=f"{client.user.avatar_url}")
    seconds = 0
    if reminder is None:
        embed.add_field(name='Warning', value='Please specify what do you want me to remind you about.') # Error message
    if time.lower().endswith("d"):
        seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60 * 60 * 24
        counter = f"{seconds // 60 // 60 // 24} days"
    if time.lower().endswith("h"):
        seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60 * 60
        counter = f"{seconds // 60 // 60} hours"
    elif time.lower().endswith("m"):
        seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60
        counter = f"{seconds // 60} minutes"
    elif time.lower().endswith("s"):
        seconds += int(time[:-1])
        counter = f"{seconds} seconds"
    if seconds == 0:
        embed.add_field(name='Warning',
                        value='Please specify a proper duration, send `reminder_help` for more information.')
    elif seconds < 300:
        embed.add_field(name='Warning',
                        value='You have specified a too short duration!\nMinimum duration is 5 minutes.')
    elif seconds > 7776000:
        embed.add_field(name='Warning', value='You have specified a too long duration!\nMaximum duration is 90 days.')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Alright, I will remind you about {reminder} in {counter}.")
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
        await ctx.send(f"Hi, you asked me to remind you about {reminder} {counter} ago.")
        return
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

First of all, I don't know what causes the problem but you use a for loop for no reason, it's unnecessary. Then you don't have to create embeds for 4 times, you can just use `add_field`. So it works now. If you still have problem, just comment.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, but I have another question regarding that post.
Is it possible to do `if time.lower().endswith("day")` instead of `("d")`? I have tried changing it but I got a value error:
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'da'`
Can you help me with this too please?

Comment: If you do change it with `day` you should change the parts of `seconds += int(time[:-1])`. You can change it with `seconds += int(time[:-3])`.

Comment: That does work with day, thanks, but when I try to do `days` and put `(time[:-4])` it doesn't work and gives a ValueError:
Example: `/reminder 5days Hello`,

`Command raised an exception: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5day'`

Comment: Can you show the code? You must have change something that triggers the error.

Comment: It is exactly the same as the one you posted above, except I changed
``if time.lower().endswith("d"): 
       seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60 * 60 * 24``
To:
``if time.lower().endswith("days"):
      seconds += int(time[:-4]) * 60 * 60 * 24``

Comment: So, I have no answer for that, sorry.

Comment: It's all good, thank you for all of your help above, I will try and open a question tomorrow about this case to see if I get any other help.