# How we can we send a message in discord.py at a particular date and time

Tags: discord.py

I am creating a bot that sends a reminder for and particular event. Let say, we have and event which going to occur on 28th April(01) of 2021 o 3:30 PM.

I want my bot to send a message at that date and time, which is 28/04/2021 and 3:30 PM.

Please help me out.

Comment: You should include what you've already tried and we'd be able to help you in debugging your issues. If you haven't started, I'd recommend trying some thing similar to tasks. Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks

Answer (score -1):

I found a similar answer.

Does this help you out?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63659761/14141072

If still there is an issue ask me and I will post my version of it. :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: I visited that earlier. But I am not using discord.ext

Comment: can you share your versions